# Auto generate TAG in Intellij Idea and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, live-templates, android-log

I have modified my Android Studio *live templates* to write the log directly from class name as following, but I am getting this warning message.
How can I avoid it. Also, if I add `const`to the decleration I get another error:

`Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value`

Is there anyway that I can use `SomeName::class.java.simpleName` without getting any warning or error? I prefer this that writing hard-coded class name as a string.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The warning is not related to live-template or `SomeName::class.java.simpleName`, it is because of how 'TAG' variable is defined.

Mutable variables should be defined in camelCase, according to
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#property-names

> Names of top-level or object properties which hold objects with behavior or mutable data should use camel case names